# How to remove duplicate records in OpenERP ver 6.1.1

Tags: postgresql, odoo

I want to get Employee ID, Leave Reason, Leave type and Employee name for my internal report purpose. I wrote a SQL query to retrieve those data and I got some duplicates also.

Seems it's missing some join / foreign id mapping part missing

```
select
   h.id as employee_id,h.name as leave_reason,
   s.name,r.name as res_name
from 
   hr_holidays_status s,
   hr_holidays h,
   hr_employee e,
   resource_resource r
where 
   h.employee_id=e.id and 
   h.holiday_status_id=s.id and
   e.resource_id=r.id
order by 
   resource_id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query looks correct, but maybe you're getting unexpected results because the `hr_holidays` table contains both "Leave Requests" and "Leave Allocations". It's like a double-entry system where leave allocations increase the quantity of leave days available for an employee or an employee category, while leave requests decrease it.

Your query should probably take this distinction into account, and you might also want to filter on other fields like the state, because some of the records may not be validated yet.

Looking at the declaration of the [hr.holidays](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~openerp/openobject-addons/6.1/view/head:/hr_holidays/hr_holidays.py#L112) model in 6.1, you will see a few noteworthy fields that could be used in your query:

- `type`: can be *Allocation* (`'add'`) to represent an increment, or *Request* (`'remove'`) to represent a decrement
- `holiday_type`: can be *Employee* (`'employee'`), in which case the `employee_id` column indicates which employee, or *Category* (`'category'`), in which case the `category_id` column indicates which category
- `state`: *New* (`'draft'`), *Waiting Approval* (`'confirm'`), *Refused* (`'refuse'`), *Waiting Second Approval* (`'validate1'`), *Approved* (`'validate'`), *Cancelled* (`'cancel'`)

Comment: Thanks Odony..now its sorted  :-)